# Problems with YUM and Python2.7 in Fedora 17

Tags: linux, yum

yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit, yum-fast-
              : downloader

Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- fedora: ftp.freepark.org
- rpmfusion-free: rpmfusion.famillecollet.com
- rpmfusion-free-updates: rpmfusion.famillecollet.com
- rpmfusion-nonfree: rpmfusion.famillecollet.com
- rpmfusion-nonfree-updates: rpmfusion.famillecollet.com
- updates: mirror.i3d.net

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "/usr/bin/yum", line 29, in

yummain.user_main(sys.argv[1:], exit_code=True)

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 319, in user_main
    errcode = main(args)

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py", line 144, in main
    result, resultmsgs = base.doCommands()

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 485, in doCommands
    return self.yum_cli_commands[self.basecmd].doCommand(self, self.basecmd, self.extcmds)

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/yumcommands.py", line 405, in doCommand
    return base.updatePkgs(extcmds, update_to=(basecmd == 'update-to'))

File "/usr/share/yum-cli/cli.py", line 900, in updatePkgs
    self.update()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 4672, in update
    updates = self.up.getUpdatesTuples()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 1034, in 
    up = property(fget=lambda self: self._getUpdates(),

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 839, in _getUpdates
    self._up = rpmUtils.updates.Updates(self.rpmdb.simplePkgList(), self.pkgSack.simplePkgList())

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 1015, in 
    pkgSack = property(fget=lambda self: self._getSacks(),

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/**init**.py", line 779, in _getSacks
    self.repos.populateSack(which=repos)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/repos.py", line 348, in populateSack
    sack.populate(repo, mdtype, callback, cacheonly)

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 206, in populate
    xml = repo_get_function()

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1716, in getPrimaryXML
    return self.retrieveMD('primary')

File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/yum/yumRepo.py", line 1639, in retrieveMD
    return self._retrieveMD(mdtype)

File "/usr/lib/yum-plugins/yum-fast-downloader.py", line 171, in myRetrieveMD
    except Errors.RepoError:

NameError: global name 'Errors' is not defined

What can i do here, please help! Thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

@Dimitar, I would try the following:

```
yum clean all
yum clean dbcache
yum update yum
yum update
```